# Waf - Can't find local dll

Tags: python, waf

I'm experimenting on converting a makefile from another buildsystem to waf.

I'm trying to direct waf to the directory containing the necessary dlls.

However, when running waf configure:

```
Checking for library libiconv2           : not found
```

It can't find the required library.

Directory stucture:

```
project/
| build/
| inc/
| | XGetopt.h
| | common.h
| | define.h
| | libpst.h
| | libstrfunc.h
| | lzfu.h
| | msg.h
| | timeconv.h
| | vbuf.h
| libs/
| | libiconv2.dll
| | regex2.dll
| src/
| | XGetopt.c
| | debug.c
| | dumpblocks.c
| | getidblock.c
| | libpst.c
| | libstrfunc.c
| | lspst.c
| | lzfu.c
| | readpst.c
| | timeconv.c
| | vbuf.c
| | deltasearch.cpp
| | msg.cpp
| | nick2ldif.cpp
| | pst2dii.cpp
| | pst2ldif.cpp
| | wscript_build
| waf-1.7.10
| wscript
```

top-level wscript:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

VERSION = "0.1"
APPNAME = "readpst"

top = "." # The topmost directory of the waf project
out = "build/temp" # The build directory of the waf project

import os
from waflib import Build
from waflib import ConfigSet
from waflib import Logs

# Variant memory variables
var_path = out + "/variant.txt" # The variant memory file path
default_variant = "debug" # The default if no variant is stored
stored_variant = ""

def options(opt):
    '''
    A script hook function that defines addtional switch options for the build.
    '''
    opt.load("compiler_cxx")

def configure(cfg):
    '''
    A script hook function that configures the build environment.
    '''
    cfg.load("compiler_cxx")
    cfg.find_program("strip")
    cfg.env.PREFIX = "."
    cfg.env.DEFINES = ["WAF=1"]
    cfg.env.FEATURES = [] # Additional features
    cfg.env.LIBPATH = [os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "libs")]
    print cfg.env.LIBPATH
    cfg.define("VERSION", VERSION)
    base_env = cfg.env

    # Compiler checks
    cfg.check_large_file(mandatory = False)
    cfg.check_inline()

    # Check for the existance and function of specific headers
    cfg.check(header_name = "stdint.h")
    cfg.check(header_name = "stdio.h")
    cfg.check(compiler="cxx", uselib_store="LIBICONV2", mandatory=True, lib="libiconv2")

    # Define the debug build environment
    cfg.setenv("debug", env = base_env.derive())
    cfg.env.CFLAGS = ["-g"]
    cfg.define("DEBUG", 1)
    cfg.write_config_header("/debug/inc/config.h")

    # Define the release build environment
    cfg.setenv("release", env = base_env.derive())
    cfg.env.CFLAGS = ["-O2"]
    cfg.env.FEATURES = ["strip"]
    cfg.define("RELEASE", 1)
    cfg.write_config_header("/release/inc/config.h")

def pre(ctx):
    '''
    A callback for before build task start.
    '''
        print "Starting %sbuild" % (("%s " % ctx.variant) if(ctx.variant) else "")
        if ctx.cmd == "install":
        print "Installing"

def post(ctx):
    '''
    A callback for after build task finish.
    '''
    global var_path
        print "Finished %sbuild" % (("%s " % ctx.variant) if(ctx.variant) else "")
    env = ConfigSet.ConfigSet()
    env.stored_variant = ctx.variant
    env.store(var_path)

def build(bld):
    '''
    A script hook function that specifies the build behaviour.
    '''
    bld.add_pre_fun(pre)
    bld.add_post_fun(post)

    bld.recurse\
    (
        [
            "src"
        ]
    )
    if bld.cmd != "clean":
        bld.logger = Logs.make_logger("test.log", "build") # just to get a clean output

def dist(ctx):
    '''
    A script hook function that specifies the packaging behaviour.
    '''
    ctx.base_name = "_".join([APPNAME, VERSION])
    ctx.algo = "zip"
    file_ex_patterns = \
    [
        out + "/**",
        "**/.waf-1*",
        "**/*~",
        "**/*.pyc",
        "**/*.swp",
        "**/.lock-w*"
    ]
    file_in_patterns = \
    [
        "**/wscript*",
        "**/*.h",
        "**/*.c",
        "**/*.cpp",
        "**/*.txt",
    ]
    ctx.files = ctx.path.ant_glob(incl = file_in_patterns, excl = file_ex_patterns)

def set_variant():
    '''
    A function that facilitates dynamic changing of the Context classes variant member.
    It retrieves the stored variant, if existant, otherwise the default.
    '''
    global default_variant
    global stored_variant
    global var_path
    env = ConfigSet.ConfigSet()
    try:
        env.load(var_path)
    except:
        stored_variant = default_variant
    else:
        if(env.stored_variant):
            stored_variant = env.stored_variant
            print "Resuming %s variant" % stored_variant
        else:
            stored_variant = default_variant

def get_variant():
    '''
    A function that facilitates dynamic changing of the Context classes variant member.
    It sets the variant, if undefined, and returns.
    '''
    global stored_variant
    if(not stored_variant):
        set_variant()
    return stored_variant

class release(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the release build.
    '''
    cmd = "release"
    variant = "release" 

class debug(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the debug build.
    '''
    cmd = "debug"
    variant = "debug"

class default_build(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the default variant build.
    This is set to debug.
    '''
    variant = "debug"

class default_clean(Build.CleanContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build clean.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

class default_install(Build.InstallContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build install.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

class default_uninstall(Build.UninstallContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build uninstall.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

# Addtional features
from waflib import Task, TaskGen
class strip(Task.Task):
    run_str = "${STRIP} ${SRC}"
    color   = "BLUE"

@TaskGen.feature("strip")
@TaskGen.after("apply_link")
def add_strip_task(self):
    try:
        link_task = self.link_task
    except:
        return
    tsk = self.create_task("strip", self.link_task.outputs[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some consideration, I realised I required further information. The default error information provided by waf seems to be about waf itself, rather than the wscripts or the project.

To rectify this, **loggers need to be added**. I added loggers to the configure and build functions.

configure logger:

```
cfg.logger = Logs.make_logger("configure_%s.log" % datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d"), "configure")
```

build logger:

```
bld.logger = Logs.make_logger("build_%s.log" % datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d"), "build")
```

Doing this lead me to that nature of the problems:

```
['C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\g++.exe', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', '-Wl,--enable-auto-import', 'test.cpp.1.o', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\libpst-0.6.60\\clean\\build\\temp\\conf_check_5fe204eaa3b3bcb7a9f85e15cebb726e\\testbuild\\testprog.exe', '-Wl,-Bstatic', '-Wl,-Bdynamic', '-LC:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\libpst-0.6.60\\clean\\libs', '-llibiconv2']

err: c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\libpst-0.6.60\clean\libs/libiconv2.dll when searching for -llibiconv2
```

The library path has been passed correctly to gcc, but the dll is **32bit** whereas the gcc installation is **64bit** and so it is **incompatible**.

top-level wscript:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

VERSION = "0.1"
APPNAME = "readpst"

top = "." # The topmost directory of the waf project
out = "build/temp" # The build directory of the waf project

import os
import datetime
from waflib import Build
from waflib import ConfigSet
from waflib import Logs

# Variant memory variables
var_path = out + "/variant.txt" # The variant memory file path
default_variant = "debug" # The default if no variant is stored
stored_variant = ""

def options(opt):
    '''
    A script hook function that defines addtional switch options for the build.
    '''
    opt.load("compiler_c compiler_cxx")

def configure(cfg):
    '''
    A script hook function that configures the build environment.
    '''
    cfg.logger = Logs.make_logger("configure_%s.log" % datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d"), "configure")
    cfg.load("compiler_c compiler_cxx")
    cfg.find_program("strip")
    cfg.env.DEFINES = \
    [
        "WAF=1",
        "HAVE_CONFIG_H=1"
    ]
    cfg.env.FEATURES = [] # Additional features
    cfg.env.append_value("LIBPATH", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "libs"))
    cfg.env.append_value("INCLUDES", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "inc"))
    cfg.env.append_value("INCLUDES", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "inc", "glib-2.0"))
    cfg.env.append_value("INCLUDES", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "inc", "glib-2.0", "glib"))
    cfg.env.append_value("INCLUDES", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "libs", "regex", "2.7", "regex-2.7-src", "src"))
    cfg.env.append_value("INCLUDES", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "libs", "libiconv", "1.9.2", "libiconv-1.9.2-src", "include"))

    cfg.define("VERSION", VERSION)

    base_env = cfg.env

    # Compiler checks
    cfg.check_large_file(mandatory = False)
    cfg.check_inline()

    cfg.multicheck\
    (
        {"header_name" : "fcntl.h"},
        {"header_name" : "iostream"},
        {"header_name" : "list"},
        {"header_name" : "set"},
        {"header_name" : "string"},
        {"header_name" : "vector"},
        msg = "Checking for standard headers",
        mandatory = True
    )

    cfg.check(header_name = "glib.h", mandatory = False)
    cfg.multicheck\
    (
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-infile-stdio.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-infile.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-input-stdio.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-outfile-msole.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-outfile.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-output-stdio.h"},
        {"header_name" : "gsf\\gsf-utils.h"},
        msg = "Checking for gsf headers",
        mandatory = False
    )

    # Checking for headers expected in config.h
    cfg.check(header_name = "ctype.h",     define_name = "HAVE_CTYPE_H"    , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "dirent.h",    define_name = "HAVE_DIRENT_H"   , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "errno.h",     define_name = "HAVE_ERRNO_H"    , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "gd.h",        define_name = "HAVE_GD_H"       , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "iconv.h",     define_name = "HAVE_ICON"       , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "limits.h",    define_name = "HAVE_LIMITS_H"   , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "regex.h",     define_name = "HAVE_REGEX_H"    , mandatory = False)
    #cfg.check(header_name = "semaphore.h", define_name = "HAVE_SEMAPHORE_H", mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "signal.h",    define_name = "HAVE_SIGNAL_H"   , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "string.h",    define_name = "HAVE_STRING_H"   , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "sys/shm.h",   define_name = "HAVE_SYS_SHM_H"  , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "sys/stat.h",  define_name = "HAVE_SYS_STAT_H" , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "sys/types.h", define_name = "HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H", mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "sys/wait.h",  define_name = "HAVE_SYS_WAIT_H" , mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "wchar.h",     define_name = "HAVE_WCHAR_H"    , mandatory = False)

    cfg.check(header_name = "define.h", mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "lzfu.h", mandatory = False)
    cfg.check(header_name = "msg.h", mandatory = False)

    # Check for the existance and function of specific headers
    cfg.check_cxx(lib = "libiconv2", uselib_store = "LIBICONV2", mandatory = False)

    # Define the debug build environment
    cfg.setenv("debug", env = base_env.derive())
    cfg.env.append_value("CFLAGS", "-g")
    cfg.define("DEBUG", 1)
    cfg.write_config_header("/debug/inc/config.h")

    # Define the release build environment
    cfg.setenv("release", env = base_env.derive())
    cfg.env.append_value("CFLAGS", "-02")
    cfg.env.FEATURES = ["strip"]
    cfg.define("RELEASE", 1)
    cfg.write_config_header("/release/inc/config.h")

def pre(ctx):
    '''
    A callback for before build task start.
    '''
        print "Starting %sbuild" % (("%s " % ctx.variant) if(ctx.variant) else "")
        if ctx.cmd == "install":
        print "Installing"

def post(ctx):
    '''
    A callback for after build task finish.
    '''
    global var_path
        print "Finished %sbuild" % (("%s " % ctx.variant) if(ctx.variant) else "")
    env = ConfigSet.ConfigSet()
    env.stored_variant = ctx.variant
    env.store(var_path)

def build(bld):
    '''
    A script hook function that specifies the build behaviour.
    '''
    if bld.cmd != "clean":
        bld.logger = Logs.make_logger("build_%s.log" % datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y_%m_%d"), "build")
    bld.add_pre_fun(pre)
    bld.add_post_fun(post)

    bld.recurse\
    (
        [
            "src"
        ]
    )

def dist(ctx):
    '''
    A script hook function that specifies the packaging behaviour.
    '''
    ctx.base_name = "_".join([APPNAME, VERSION])
    ctx.algo = "zip"
    file_ex_patterns = \
    [
        out + "/**",
        "**/.waf-1*",
        "**/*~",
        "**/*.pyc",
        "**/*.swp",
        "**/.lock-w*"
    ]
    file_in_patterns = \
    [
        "**/wscript*",
        "**/*.h",
        "**/*.c",
        "**/*.cpp",
        "**/*.txt",
    ]
    ctx.files = ctx.path.ant_glob(incl = file_in_patterns, excl = file_ex_patterns)

def set_variant():
    '''
    A function that facilitates dynamic changing of the Context classes variant member.
    It retrieves the stored variant, if existant, otherwise the default.
    '''
    global default_variant
    global stored_variant
    global var_path
    env = ConfigSet.ConfigSet()
    try:
        env.load(var_path)
    except:
        stored_variant = default_variant
    else:
        if(env.stored_variant):
            stored_variant = env.stored_variant
            print "Resuming %s variant" % stored_variant
        else:
            stored_variant = default_variant

def get_variant():
    '''
    A function that facilitates dynamic changing of the Context classes variant member.
    It sets the variant, if undefined, and returns.
    '''
    global stored_variant
    if(not stored_variant):
        set_variant()
    return stored_variant

class release(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the release build.
    '''
    cmd = "release"
    variant = "release" 

class debug(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the debug build.
    '''
    cmd = "debug"
    variant = "debug"

class default_build(Build.BuildContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the default variant build.
    This is set to debug.
    '''
    variant = "debug"

class default_clean(Build.CleanContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build clean.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

class default_install(Build.InstallContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build install.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

class default_uninstall(Build.UninstallContext):
    '''
    A class that provides the stored variant build uninstall.
    '''
    @property
    def variant(self):
        return get_variant()

# Addtional features
from waflib import Task, TaskGen
class strip(Task.Task):
    run_str = "${STRIP} ${SRC}"
    color   = "BLUE"

@TaskGen.feature("strip")
@TaskGen.after("apply_link")
def add_strip_task(self):
    try:
        link_task = self.link_task
    except:
        return
    tsk = self.create_task("strip", self.link_task.outputs[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You just lack the `use` variable setup, but this has to be fixed in your child-wscripts, i.e.

```
bld.program (...,
    libpath = ['/usr/lib', 'subpath'], #this has to be relative to the wscript it appears in! (or the root wscript, can not recall)
    ...,
    use = ['iconv2', 'regex2'] )
```

See section 9.1.2 of the [waf book](http://docs.waf.googlecode.com/git/book_17/single.html)

---

**Alternatively:** (and probably the cleaner version)

```
cfg.check_cc(lib='iconv2', uselib_store="LIBICONV2", mandatory=True)
```

and then use `uselib` with

```
bld.program (...,
    libpath = ['/usr/lib', 'subpath'], #this has to be relative to the wscript it appears in! (or the root wscript, can not recall)
    ...,
    uselib = ['LIBICONV2', ...] )
```

Comment: I'm focusing on the cfg checks at the moment. I've changed the check to:  cfg.check(compiler="cxx", uselib_store="LIBICONV2", mandatory=True, use="libiconv2")
however, I now get AssertionError: invalid parameters

Comment: You can not use the `use` directive within the cfg.check, updated answer above with an alternative way

Comment: Still the same error as before: libiconv2 not found. Is it related to the extension being ".dll" instead of ".a",".lib" or ".so"  ?

Comment: Not sure, I think waf does that automatically. But if you use a `.dll` I think you need to keep the `lib` prefix i.e. `libiconv2`. But do not cite me on that, consider this more of a uneducated guess.

Comment: replacing `check_cxx` instead of `check_cc` might be useful too, but should not changed anything in this case

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057642/finding-local-external-libraries-with-waf

Comment: Yes, I've also had a look at that link and it doesn't yield a solution for me. If there were a way to get more meaningful errors out of Waf (I've tried the -vvv switch) in regards to paths and finding resources, it might assist further.

Comment: I just had a look at one of my wscript files, and what I do additionally in the build part is `bld.read_shlib ('library_name_without_pre_or_suffix', paths=['local_relative_path'])` – without it would refuse to compile

Comment: Presumably that shouldn't affect the configure process? I know when comes to building, that will have to happen, but that fact that it can't find the library in the first place is concerning.

Comment: End of knowlege reached, best is to post in the google group for waf